# Adding a method to a class using .prototype

Tags: javascript, class, oop, prototype, es5-compatiblity

I am attempting to define a class called "User"... then further along in the code I am trying to add a method to the class by writing to "prototype".
I'm not sure if my terminology is correct here... though I would like to have the method "who_auto" available to all future instances of "User"...

Trying out this code in JSFiddle... is giving me the error message:
"Uncaught TypeError: pp.who_auto is not a function"

Here's my code:

```js
class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.chatroom = null;
  }

  who() {
    return `I am ${this.name}`;
  }
}

User.prototype = {
  who_auto: function() {
    console.log(`
  Hello, I am ${this.name}
  `);
  }
}
const pp = new User('peter parker');
console.log(pp);
console.log(pp.who());

pp.who_auto();
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't *replace* the entire `prototype`: `User.prototype.who_auto = function () ...`!

Comment: Hmmm "probably"... I like your thinking... there are no definites in life... haha Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwritten the prototype instead of adding a property to the prototype. Below codes works.

```js
class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.chatroom = null;
  }

  who() {
    return `I am ${this.name}`;
  }
}

User.prototype.who_auto = function() {
  console.log(`Hello, I am ${this.name}`);
}

const pp = new User('peter parker');
console.log(pp);
console.log(pp.who());

pp.who_auto();
```

Comment: ```
const User = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.chatroom = null;
}

User.prototype = {
  send: function(message, to) {
    this.chatroom.send(message, this, to);
  },
  recieve: function(message, from) {
    console.log(`${from.name} to ${this.name}: ${message}`);
  }
}

const Chatroom = function() {
  let users = {}; // list of users

  return {
    register: function(user) {
      users[user.name] = user;
      user.chatroom = this;
    }
  }
}
```
Mark, I've been working along with this tutorial and it is striking me as strange why the above works

Comment: Probably should have added that to the original post.. thanks Mark